# can maven clean delete deleted dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I have many dependencies in pom.xml. As I go through my project, I installed dependencies which are not used anymore(due to trial and error).

So I deleted dependencies which are not used anymore in pom.xml. 
Performed mvn clean then mvn install.
Does the dependencies which I deleted in pom.xml no longer exist in maven repository?

Comment: They still exist in your `~/.m2/repository` folder.

Comment: Delete contents of your m2 folder and then call mvn install from command line where pwd is your project home.

Answer (score 2):

`mvn clean` do not clean your repository. It only cleans the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually, as commented by @Arnaud, or you might prefer an automated way using the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) with the `purge-local-repository` goal on a project which declares your deleted dependencies only:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Purging local repository dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html) you need to do that. But this is little bit tricky. So be careful while you are using it.

I think `dependency:purge-local-repository` and Optional Parameter `excludes` will help you.

`excludes` nothing but : *The list of dependencies in the form of groupId:artifactId which should NOT be deleted/refreshed.*

For full documentation see [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html).